# error running GAE dev_appserver.py on Ubuntu

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ubuntu, dev-appserver

#### environment: ubuntu-x32bit / python2.7 / gae 1.8.1

Running the `dev_appserver.py` throws the following error:

```
$ python dev_appserver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dev_appserver.py", line 182, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "dev_appserver.py", line 178, in _run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/home/adminuser/dev/apps/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 30, in <module>
    from google.appengine.datastore import datastore_stub_util
  File "/home/adminuser/dev/apps/gae/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_stub_util.py", line 193
    datastore_types.SCATTER_SPECIAL_PROPERTY:.get(prefix, (0, et_bdatastore#!/usr/bihOPERTY:.get(preob.Pth the actual:
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried these:

`apt-get build-dep python`

`python dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore=yes ../path/to_app`

`echo $PATH`

`/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/adminuser/dev/apps/gae/google_appengine/:/home/adminuser/dev/apps/gae/google_appengine/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your distribution of the SDK is corrupt.

LIne 193 of datastore_stub_util.py look like

```
datastore_types.SCATTER_SPECIAL_PROPERTY: (False, True, _GetScatterProperty)
```

I would re download it.

Regards

Tim

Comment: hmm.. ok, so a suggestive option would be to re download & delete the GAE app engines folder & then export the gae's path?

Comment: I would definately redownload it.  I don't ever export the path.  I use explicit command line  python <path to sdk>/dev_appserver.py <path to project>  but thats just how I do it.

Comment: Hmmm.. even I do run the dev_server same as you do, explicitly. thanks for your input, I had the earlier version on disk, re-extracting it didn't help either got a new traceback, so downloaded newest version 1.8.5 .. this worked.